# VSCode open multi files

Tags: php, visual-studio-code

when i open files in vscode, on files already is written deleted. How do I solve this problem?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35rRm.png)

Comment: Given the path of your file, I assume it's a local copy downloaded through a FTP/SCP client. That file was probably deleted when you closed your FTP/SCP client and it remains in the editor, marked as deleted. If you want to edit multiple files at once in the long run, download a local copy of your project.

Comment: I don't really understand your description without guessing. Also, what would make a solution for you? You don't say what you expect. Further, there's no relation to PHP in your question, as far as I can tell. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Go to `File -> Preferences -> Settings` and search for "`Close on file delete`". Check this box in order for vscode to **close** the tab of whatever file you delete. This happens because you deleted the file manually instead of deleting from vscode.